# tool to find out which video card is installed on my system?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card

is there one for Win XP?

- dxdiag, msinfo, etc do not show anything but 'generic VGA'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for seeing `Generic VGA` is because you do not have the correct graphics driver installed and are using the Windows default drivers.

I highly recommend you try [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/), Whilst with drivers it is very accurate and can detect many manufacturers and models, without the correct drivers installed, it is 50/50 and I have had mixed results.

Next, I would try [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy), but if GPU-Z fails, this most likely will not work.

If both of the above fail, a fool proof solution is to go to `Device Manager` then Double click on the `Generic VGA` icon and go to the `Details` tab then look for the long device ID which should look something similar to `PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_9612&SUBSYS_3656103C&REV_00` and Google it (or copy it to your question and you should get an answer).

The vendor IDs (for the most popular ones) are:

```
0x1002   ATI / AMD graphics
0x10DE   Nvidia
0x163C   intel
0x102B   Matrox
0x10A9   Silicon Graphics
0x5333   S3 Graphics Co., Ltd
```

For a full list of not just graphics vendors, [look here](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendors.php?sort=id)

As for device ID, there are far too many to list. [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) has a good search tool, if this fails, try Google.

Comment: thanks, Speccy did not work as well. the reason i want to know the type of the card is to download the drivers ;)

Comment: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_5B72&SUBSYS_0F031002&REV_00\4&123D6358&0&0110 googling for it brought me to ati2mtag.sys, so I went to ATI site and downloaded a Catalyst suite. will see how this goes after reboot

Comment: Brilliant, glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

[Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/products/everest-pc-diagnostics) generally works for me although its not free, you can have a go with the trial version though.

Answer (score 1):

Mark I Eyeball.  Open the case and look.  There should be a label the will provide that information.  Lacking a sticker, look for a block of information screened onto the card itself that will have part/model information.

Comment: lazy... hoped for a solution similar to Linux' lspci

Comment: And MK-1 Iball doesn't always work. Some vendors are VERY reluctant to tell you or even let you see what's on the card (ie whole card heat spreader/fan shrouds).