# How to know my graphics card in my laptop?

Tags: dell-inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect the model of my graphics card?](https://superuser.com/questions/184932/how-can-i-detect-the-model-of-my-graphics-card)

I want to run gta 4 and don't want to waste my money by throwing it. I have dell inspiron 1525 T4200, dual-core,3 GB ram,358 MB, 2.00 GhZ, 32bit OS and Windows 7 ULtimate. PLease help me to know my graphics card!!!

Answer (score 2):

Click on the start orb, in the "search" box type in dxdiag and press enter

Click no on the first box, and then click on the display tab. The left panel will tell you what graphics card you have, and the right box will tell you what the driver is.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out in Device Manager.  Go to the Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Device Manager.  A list of all your computer's hardware will appear.  Expand the Display Adapters to see your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

if you have [dell](http://support.dell.com/support/index.aspx?~ck=pn) then you have dell support. If that doesn't help you, I recommend "[everest](http://www.lavalys.com/)" from lavalys.

There is also a system information (type system information in "start") which displays every aspect of your computer (graphic card is under components/display)