# Screen Flashes/Flickers to Black When Opening PowerPoint 2010

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

As soon I open PowerPoint 2010 on my Windows XP desktop (does not matter if I open it directly or by double-clicking on a PowerPoint file), the entire screen starts flashing/flickering between normal and a solid black screen for a second or two. Then it stays solid black. If you leave it in this state it will eventually return normal, but only for a second or so before it goes back to being completely black. The only way to get out of this is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. I do not have this problem if I use PowerPoint 2003, and I still have the problem if I open PowerPoint 2010 in Safe Mode.

Comment: Note this is not an issue I had myself, but since I already know and have posted the answer with the question, I decided to write it in the first person. However, this was an issue that one of the users I support at work had. If you know any other solutions (especially better ones), please feel free to post them as an answer and I will try them as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution #1

Go to the manufacturer's web-site of your graphics card, and download the latest driver that is available for your card. See the post titled [How can I detect the model of my graphics card?](https://superuser.com/questions/184932/how-can-i-detect-the-model-of-my-graphics-card) if you do not know how to determine what make & model of graphics card you have.

### Solution #2

If you have already tried upgrading your driver, or for whatever reason you cannot upgrade to a newer driver. Then you can work around the issue by turning *ON* the *Disable hardware graphics acceleration* option in PowerPoint 2010 under **File > Options > Advanced > Display**. However, since you can't open PowerPoint normally, or via Safe Mode then you will have to do it via a registry setting.

1. Click on **Start > Run** and type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on the **OK** button. This will open the Windows Registry Editor.
2. Navigate down the tree on the left as follows: **Computer > HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Office > 14.0 > Gfx**.
3. Look on the right hand side for an entry named *DisableHardware*, if you do not see it, then right click on a blank area or on the **Gfx** tree node and click on **New > DWORD (32-bit) Value** and name it `DisableHardware`.
4. Double click on *DisabledHardware* or right click on it and select **Modify...**
5. In the **Edit DWORD (32-bit) Value** dialog that comes up, enter a one (`1`) for the *Value data* field and click on **OK**.